# trying to save tweets into a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter

so I feel like I've got the pieces for this one but unable to solve the puzzle.

So I have a User model, that can follow several keywords (queries). The association is like this:

User

```
 has_many :campaigns #they can add and remove keywords to this association
 has_many :alerts, through: campaigns
```

Now what I would like to do is create a method that searches through those User.campaigns, an saves them in the alerts. Thus I can see what query is connected to which keyword (through campaign_id).

Here's what I have:

```
keywords = current_user.campaigns.map(&:keywords)

current_user.twitter.search(keywords, result_type: 'recent').take(5).collect do |tweet|
 "#{tweet.id} #{tweet.user.id}"
end
```

Now there's a problem with my code, which is that keyword is an array. What I want it to do is search through the array one at a time.

Then I want to save it into the Alert table. Where I have the columns 'tweet_id' and 'owner_id' and the 'campaign_id'.

Ideally I have a cron job that does this every 15 minutes.

I have no clue where to start with this. Any ideas?

Comment: So your first problem is that you have an array and you want to search for every of its items, right?

Comment: yes so my array has 4 elements. I'd like to take 5 queries from each. Totaling to 20

Comment: I am not sure I understand: What does your `twitter.search` method return?

Comment: It returns a tweet that matches the specified query. Here are the docs: http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/twitter/Twitter/REST/Search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you're looking for is how to search on each individual keyword, something like this should do it:
*edited based on clarification from OP*

```
current_user.campaigns.each do |campaign|
  current_user.twitter.search(campaign.keyword, result_type: 'recent').take(5).map do |tweet|
   "#{tweet.id} #{tweet.user.id}"
   #new_alert = current_user.alerts.create(campaign: campaign....)
  end
end
```

Note that there might be a way to have twitter.search return only 5 results, which would make the .take call unnecessary.

Note also that I swapped your .map and .collect - they're mostly interchangeable, but semantically .collect to me means "retrieve some values" and .map means "take some action on each value".

Does that help?

Comment: Score! Now I'm retrieving them correctly. Now what I'd like to do is save them into the model called Alerts. Where also the campaign_id ends up being right.

Comment: they're unique to the User. That's why I'm thinking if I can get the id of the keyword I'm going through, and save that as the campaign_id that'd be the best

Comment: I was really asking if a user can create more than one campaign with the same keyword. Regardless, I'll edit my answer slightly.

Comment: It can not. Thanks for the help so far any idea on the creation part?

Comment: The commented-out line in my answer should get you started - you've got the campaign there, so you can pass it along to the Alert creation. Does that make sense, or am I missing what you're asking?

Comment: I tried to add this method in the user model and got Cannot modify association 'User#alerts' because the source reflection class 'Alerts' is associated to 'Campaign' via :has_many.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73189/discussion-between-sja-and-matt).

Comment: @sja Don't forget to accept this as the answer to your question.